# war servlet tomcat cannot find

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

i exported my servlet project from eclipse as a war file and i placed it inside webapp/hello folder.

/webapps/hello/hellotest.war

How do i run it ?

i typed this

http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/foo

but it fails to run

this is my web.xml file inside the war file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>helloTest</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <description>
        </description>
        <display-name>foo</display-name>
        <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
        foo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>foo</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using tomcat? What is the directory structure under webapps after you have restarted tomcat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your `hellotest.war` file in the `webapps` folder of Tomcat. Assuming your Tomcat instance is running and set up properly, it should automatically deploy the application to folder `webapps/hellotest`. You can then access your application from URL `http://127.0.0.1:8080/hellotest/`.